# BottomNavigationView, переключение между activity

Tags: java, android, navigationbar

Здравствуйте
Я только начинающий и прошу не судить строго и помочь.
Проблема состоит в том, что я имею 5 кнопок на BottomNavigationBar и вопрос в том, как реализовать переключение, то есть чтобы по нажатию кнопки выводилась другая информация, нужно ли создавать другие activity ? 
Далее привожу код.

```
package --------;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class Navigation extends AppCompatActivity {



private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_lists:

                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_sale:

                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_maps:

                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_regulation:

                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}

}
```

Возможно, это очень просто, но нуждаюсь в помощи.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: `BottomNavigationBar` обычно используется для переключения фрагментов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Активити должна быть одна, в которой внизу находится `BottomNavigationView`. При нажатии на вкладку должен подменяться `Fragment` в той части активити, в которой находится изменяемый контент.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Здесь `content` - это `layout`, в который помещается фрагмент (и соответственно подменяется на новый).

Есть и альтернативы фрагментам в виде View-based концепций, например `Conductor`, но для новичков, полезно сначала поработать именно с фрагментами.